# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 54: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pytorch, setuptools

I know there are a lot of answers for this type of problem but I cannot apply them to my code due to my limited knowledge about programming.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import copy
import glob
import imp
import os
import re
import setuptools
import subprocess
import sys
import sysconfig
import tempfile
import warnings

import torch
from .file_baton import FileBaton
from ._cpp_extension_versioner import ExtensionVersioner

from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


IS_WINDOWS = sys.platform == 'win32'

def _find_cuda_home():
    '''Finds the CUDA install path.'''
    # Guess #1
    cuda_home = os.environ.get('CUDA_HOME') or os.environ.get('CUDA_PATH')
    if cuda_home is None:
        # Guess #2
        if IS_WINDOWS:
            cuda_homes = glob.glob(
                'C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v*.*')
            if len(cuda_homes) == 0:
                cuda_home = ''
            else:
                cuda_home = cuda_homes[0]
        else:
            cuda_home = '/usr/local/cuda'
        if not os.path.exists(cuda_home):
            # Guess #3
            try:
                which = 'where' if IS_WINDOWS else 'which'
                nvcc = subprocess.check_output(
                    [which, 'nvcc']).decode().rstrip('\r\n')
                cuda_home = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(nvcc))
            except Exception:
                cuda_home = None
    if cuda_home and not torch.cuda.is_available():
        print("No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='{}'".format(cuda_home))
    return cuda_home

MINIMUM_GCC_VERSION = (4, 9, 0)
MINIMUM_MSVC_VERSION = (19, 0, 24215)
ABI_INCOMPATIBILITY_WARNING = 

WRONG_COMPILER_WARNING = 

CUDA_HOME = _find_cuda_home()
CUDNN_HOME = os.environ.get('CUDNN_HOME') or os.environ.get('CUDNN_PATH')

BUILT_FROM_SOURCE_VERSION_PATTERN = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\w+\+\w+')

COMMON_NVCC_FLAGS = [
    '-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__',
    '-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__',
    '-D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__',
]

JIT_EXTENSION_VERSIONER = ExtensionVersioner()

def _is_binary_build():
    return not BUILT_FROM_SOURCE_VERSION_PATTERN.match(torch.version.__version__)


def _accepted_compilers_for_platform():
    return ['clang++', 'clang'] if sys.platform.startswith('darwin') else ['g++', 'gcc']


def get_default_build_root():
 
    return os.path.realpath(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'torch_extensions'))


def check_compiler_ok_for_platform(compiler):

    if IS_WINDOWS:
        return True
    which = subprocess.check_output(['which', compiler], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    # Use os.path.realpath to resolve any symlinks, in particular from 'c++' to e.g. 'g++'.
    compiler_path = os.path.realpath(which.decode().strip())
    return any(name in compiler_path for name in _accepted_compilers_for_platform())


def check_compiler_abi_compatibility(compiler):
    '''
    Verifies that the given compiler is ABI-compatible with PyTorch.
    '''
    if not _is_binary_build():
        return True
    if os.environ.get('TORCH_DONT_CHECK_COMPILER_ABI') in ['ON', '1', 'YES', 'TRUE', 'Y']:
        return True

    # First check if the compiler is one of the expected ones for the particular platform.
    if not check_compiler_ok_for_platform(compiler):
        warnings.warn(WRONG_COMPILER_WARNING.format(
            user_compiler=compiler,
            pytorch_compiler=_accepted_compilers_for_platform()[0],
            platform=sys.platform))
        return False

    if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        
        return True
    try:
        if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
            minimum_required_version = MINIMUM_GCC_VERSION
            version = subprocess.check_output([compiler, '-dumpfullversion', '-dumpversion'])
            version = version.decode().strip().split('.')
        else:
            minimum_required_version = MINIMUM_MSVC_VERSION
            compiler_info = subprocess.check_output(compiler, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            match = re.search(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', compiler_info.decode().strip())
            version = (0, 0, 0) if match is None else match.groups()
    except Exception:
        _, error, _ = sys.exc_info()
        warnings.warn('Error checking compiler version for {}: {}'.format(compiler, error))
        return False

    if tuple(map(int, version)) >= minimum_required_version:
        return True

    compiler = '{} {}'.format(compiler, ".".join(version))
    warnings.warn(ABI_INCOMPATIBILITY_WARNING.format(compiler))

    return False

class BuildExtension(build_ext, object):

    @classmethod
    def with_options(cls, **options):
        
        def init_with_options(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs = kwargs.copy()
            kwargs.update(options)
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return init_with_options

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuildExtension, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.no_python_abi_suffix = kwargs.get("no_python_abi_suffix", False)

    def build_extensions(self):
        self._check_abi()
        for extension in self.extensions:
            self._add_compile_flag(extension, '-DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H')
            self._define_torch_extension_name(extension)
            self._add_gnu_abi_flag_if_binary(extension)

        # Register .cu and .cuh as valid source extensions.
        self.compiler.src_extensions += ['.cu', '.cuh']
        # Save the original _compile method for later.
        if self.compiler.compiler_type == 'msvc':
            self.compiler._cpp_extensions += ['.cu', '.cuh']
            original_compile = self.compiler.compile
            original_spawn = self.compiler.spawn
        else:
            original_compile = self.compiler._compile

        def unix_wrap_compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts):
            # Copy before we make any modifications.
            cflags = copy.deepcopy(extra_postargs)
            try:
                original_compiler = self.compiler.compiler_so
                if _is_cuda_file(src):
                    nvcc = _join_cuda_home('bin', 'nvcc')
                    if not isinstance(nvcc, list):
                        nvcc = [nvcc]
                    self.compiler.set_executable('compiler_so', nvcc)
                    if isinstance(cflags, dict):
                        cflags = cflags['nvcc']
                    cflags = COMMON_NVCC_FLAGS + ['--compiler-options', "'-fPIC'"] + cflags
                elif isinstance(cflags, dict):
                    cflags = cflags['cxx']
                # NVCC does not allow multiple -std to be passed, so we avoid
                # overriding the option if the user explicitly passed it.
                if not any(flag.startswith('-std=') for flag in cflags):
                    cflags.append('-std=c++11')

                original_compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, cflags, pp_opts)
            finally:
                # Put the original compiler back in place.
                self.compiler.set_executable('compiler_so', original_compiler)

        def win_wrap_compile(sources,
                             output_dir=None,
                             macros=None,
                             include_dirs=None,
                             debug=0,
                             extra_preargs=None,
                             extra_postargs=None,
                             depends=None):

            self.cflags = copy.deepcopy(extra_postargs)
            extra_postargs = None

            def spawn(cmd):
                
                src_regex = re.compile('/T(p|c)(.*)')
                src_list = [
                    m.group(2) for m in (src_regex.match(elem) for elem in cmd)
                    if m
                ]

                obj_regex = re.compile('/Fo(.*)')
                obj_list = [
                    m.group(1) for m in (obj_regex.match(elem) for elem in cmd)
                    if m
                ]

                include_regex = re.compile(r'((\-|\/)I.*)')
                include_list = [
                    m.group(1)
                    for m in (include_regex.match(elem) for elem in cmd) if m
                ]

                if len(src_list) >= 1 and len(obj_list) >= 1:
                    src = src_list[0]
                    obj = obj_list[0]
                    if _is_cuda_file(src):
                        nvcc = _join_cuda_home('bin', 'nvcc')
                        if isinstance(self.cflags, dict):
                            cflags = self.cflags['nvcc']
                        elif isinstance(self.cflags, list):
                            cflags = self.cflags
                        else:
                            cflags = []
                        cmd = [
                            nvcc, '-c', src, '-o', obj, '-Xcompiler',
                            '/wd4819', '-Xcompiler', '/MD'
                        ] + include_list + cflags
                    elif isinstance(self.cflags, dict):
                        cflags = self.cflags['cxx']
                        cmd += cflags
                    elif isinstance(self.cflags, list):
                        cflags = self.cflags
                        cmd += cflags

                return original_spawn(cmd)

            try:
                self.compiler.spawn = spawn
                return original_compile(sources, output_dir, macros,
                                        include_dirs, debug, extra_preargs,
                                        extra_postargs, depends)
            finally:
                self.compiler.spawn = original_spawn

  
        if self.compiler.compiler_type == 'msvc':
            self.compiler.compile = win_wrap_compile
        else:
            self.compiler._compile = unix_wrap_compile

        build_ext.build_extensions(self)

    def get_ext_filename(self, ext_name):

        ext_filename = super(BuildExtension, self).get_ext_filename(ext_name)

        if self.no_python_abi_suffix and sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
         
            ext_filename_parts = ext_filename.split('.')
          
            without_abi = ext_filename_parts[:-2] + ext_filename_parts[-1:]
            ext_filename = '.'.join(without_abi)
        return ext_filename

    def _check_abi(self):
        
        if hasattr(self.compiler, 'compiler_cxx'):
            compiler = self.compiler.compiler_cxx[0]
        elif IS_WINDOWS:
            compiler = os.environ.get('CXX', 'cl')
        else:
            compiler = os.environ.get('CXX', 'c++')
        check_compiler_abi_compatibility(compiler)

    def _add_compile_flag(self, extension, flag):
        extension.extra_compile_args = copy.copy(extension.extra_compile_args)
        if isinstance(extension.extra_compile_args, dict):
            for args in extension.extra_compile_args.values():
                args.append(flag)
        else:
            extension.extra_compile_args.append(flag)

    def _define_torch_extension_name(self, extension):

        names = extension.name.split('.')
        name = names[-1]
        define = '-DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME={}'.format(name)
        self._add_compile_flag(extension, define)

    def _add_gnu_abi_flag_if_binary(self, extension):

        if _is_binary_build():
            self._add_compile_flag(extension, '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0')


def CppExtension(name, sources, *args, **kwargs):

    include_dirs = kwargs.get('include_dirs', [])
    include_dirs += include_paths()
    kwargs['include_dirs'] = include_dirs

    if IS_WINDOWS:
        library_dirs = kwargs.get('library_dirs', [])
        library_dirs += library_paths()
        kwargs['library_dirs'] = library_dirs

        libraries = kwargs.get('libraries', [])
        libraries.append('c10')
        libraries.append('caffe2')
        libraries.append('torch')
        libraries.append('torch_python')
        libraries.append('_C')
        kwargs['libraries'] = libraries

    kwargs['language'] = 'c++'
    return setuptools.Extension(name, sources, *args, **kwargs)

def CUDAExtension(name, sources, *args, **kwargs):
    
    library_dirs = kwargs.get('library_dirs', [])
    library_dirs += library_paths(cuda=True)
    kwargs['library_dirs'] = library_dirs

    libraries = kwargs.get('libraries', [])
    libraries.append('cudart')
    if IS_WINDOWS:
        libraries.append('c10')
        libraries.append('caffe2')
        libraries.append('torch')
        libraries.append('torch_python')
        libraries.append('caffe2_gpu')
        libraries.append('_C')
    kwargs['libraries'] = libraries

    include_dirs = kwargs.get('include_dirs', [])
    include_dirs += include_paths(cuda=True)
    kwargs['include_dirs'] = include_dirs

    kwargs['language'] = 'c++'

    return setuptools.Extension(name, sources, *args, **kwargs)

def include_paths(cuda=False):

    here = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    torch_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(here))
    lib_include = os.path.join(torch_path, 'lib', 'include')
    paths = [
        lib_include,

        os.path.join(lib_include, 'torch', 'csrc', 'api', 'include'),

        os.path.join(lib_include, 'TH'),
        os.path.join(lib_include, 'THC')
    ]
    if cuda:
        paths.append(_join_cuda_home('include'))
        if CUDNN_HOME is not None:
            paths.append(os.path.join(CUDNN_HOME, 'include'))
    return paths


def library_paths(cuda=False):

    paths = []

    if IS_WINDOWS:
        here = os.path.abspath(__file__)
        torch_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(here))
        lib_path = os.path.join(torch_path, 'lib')

        paths.append(lib_path)

    if cuda:
        lib_dir = 'lib/x64' if IS_WINDOWS else 'lib64'
        paths.append(_join_cuda_home(lib_dir))
        if CUDNN_HOME is not None:
            paths.append(os.path.join(CUDNN_HOME, lib_dir))
    return paths

def load(name,
         sources,
         extra_cflags=None,
         extra_cuda_cflags=None,
         extra_ldflags=None,
         extra_include_paths=None,
         build_directory=None,
         verbose=False,
         with_cuda=None,
         is_python_module=True):

    return _jit_compile(
        name,
        [sources] if isinstance(sources, str) else sources,
        extra_cflags,
        extra_cuda_cflags,
        extra_ldflags,
        extra_include_paths,
        build_directory or _get_build_directory(name, verbose),
        verbose,
        with_cuda,
        is_python_module)


def load_inline(name,
                cpp_sources,
                cuda_sources=None,
                functions=None,
                extra_cflags=None,
                extra_cuda_cflags=None,
                extra_ldflags=None,
                extra_include_paths=None,
                build_directory=None,
                verbose=False,
                with_cuda=None,
                is_python_module=True):

    build_directory = build_directory or _get_build_directory(name, verbose)

    if isinstance(cpp_sources, str):
        cpp_sources = [cpp_sources]
    cuda_sources = cuda_sources or []
    if isinstance(cuda_sources, str):
        cuda_sources = [cuda_sources]

    cpp_sources.insert(0, '#include ')

    if functions is not None:
        cpp_sources.append('PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m) {')
        if isinstance(functions, str):
            functions = [functions]
        if isinstance(functions, list):
            # Make the function docstring the same as the function name.
            functions = dict((f, f) for f in functions)
        elif not isinstance(functions, dict):
            raise ValueError(
                "Expected 'functions' to be a list or dict, but was {}".format(
                    type(functions)))
        for function_name, docstring in functions.items():
            cpp_sources.append('m.def("{0}", &{0}, "{1}");'.format(
                function_name, docstring))
        cpp_sources.append('}')

    cpp_source_path = os.path.join(build_directory, 'main.cpp')
    with open(cpp_source_path, 'w') as cpp_source_file:
        cpp_source_file.write('\n'.join(cpp_sources))

    sources = [cpp_source_path]

    if cuda_sources:
        cuda_sources.insert(0, '#include ')
        cuda_sources.insert(1, '#include ')
        cuda_sources.insert(2, '#include ')

        cuda_source_path = os.path.join(build_directory, 'cuda.cu')
        with open(cuda_source_path, 'w') as cuda_source_file:
            cuda_source_file.write('\n'.join(cuda_sources))

        sources.append(cuda_source_path)

    return _jit_compile(
        name,
        sources,
        extra_cflags,
        extra_cuda_cflags,
        extra_ldflags,
        extra_include_paths,
        build_directory,
        verbose,
        with_cuda,
        is_python_module)


def _jit_compile(name,
                 sources,
                 extra_cflags,
                 extra_cuda_cflags,
                 extra_ldflags,
                 extra_include_paths,
                 build_directory,
                 verbose,
                 with_cuda,
                 is_python_module):
    old_version = JIT_EXTENSION_VERSIONER.get_version(name)
    version = JIT_EXTENSION_VERSIONER.bump_version_if_changed(
        name,
        sources,
        build_arguments=[extra_cflags, extra_cuda_cflags, extra_ldflags, extra_include_paths],
        build_directory=build_directory,
        with_cuda=with_cuda
    )
    if version > 0:
        if version != old_version and verbose:
            print('The input conditions for extension module {} have changed. '.format(name) +
                  'Bumping to version {0} and re-building as {1}_v{0}...'.format(version, name))
        name = '{}_v{}'.format(name, version)

    if version != old_version:
        baton = FileBaton(os.path.join(build_directory, 'lock'))
        if baton.try_acquire():
            try:
                _write_ninja_file_and_build(
                    name=name,
                    sources=sources,
                    extra_cflags=extra_cflags or [],
                    extra_cuda_cflags=extra_cuda_cflags or [],
                    extra_ldflags=extra_ldflags or [],
                    extra_include_paths=extra_include_paths or [],
                    build_directory=build_directory,
                    verbose=verbose,
                    with_cuda=with_cuda)
            finally:
                baton.release()
        else:
            baton.wait()
    elif verbose:
        print('No modifications detected for re-loaded extension '
              'module {}, skipping build step...'.format(name))

    if verbose:
        print('Loading extension module {}...'.format(name))
    return _import_module_from_library(name, build_directory, is_python_module)


def _write_ninja_file_and_build(name,
                                sources,
                                extra_cflags,
                                extra_cuda_cflags,
                                extra_ldflags,
                                extra_include_paths,
                                build_directory,
                                verbose,
                                with_cuda):
    verify_ninja_availability()
    check_compiler_abi_compatibility(os.environ.get('CXX', 'c++'))
    if with_cuda is None:
        with_cuda = any(map(_is_cuda_file, sources))
    extra_ldflags = _prepare_ldflags(
        extra_ldflags or [],
        with_cuda,
        verbose)
    build_file_path = os.path.join(build_directory, 'build.ninja')
    if verbose:
        print(
            'Emitting ninja build file {}...'.format(build_file_path))

    _write_ninja_file(
        path=build_file_path,
        name=name,
        sources=sources,
        extra_cflags=extra_cflags or [],
        extra_cuda_cflags=extra_cuda_cflags or [],
        extra_ldflags=extra_ldflags or [],
        extra_include_paths=extra_include_paths or [],
        with_cuda=with_cuda)

    if verbose:
        print('Building extension module {}...'.format(name))
    _build_extension_module(name, build_directory, verbose)


def verify_ninja_availability():

    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as devnull:
        try:
            subprocess.check_call('ninja --version'.split(), stdout=devnull)
        except OSError:
            raise RuntimeError("Ninja is required to load C++ extensions")
        else:
            return True

def _prepare_ldflags(extra_ldflags, with_cuda, verbose):
    if IS_WINDOWS:
        python_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        python_lib_path = os.path.join(python_path, 'libs')

        here = os.path.abspath(__file__)
        torch_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(here))
        lib_path = os.path.join(torch_path, 'lib')

        extra_ldflags.append('c10.lib')
        extra_ldflags.append('caffe2.lib')
        extra_ldflags.append('torch.lib')
        extra_ldflags.append('torch_python.lib')
        if with_cuda:
            extra_ldflags.append('caffe2_gpu.lib')
        extra_ldflags.append('_C.lib')
        extra_ldflags.append('/LIBPATH:{}'.format(python_lib_path))
        extra_ldflags.append('/LIBPATH:{}'.format(lib_path))

    if with_cuda:
        if verbose:
            print('Detected CUDA files, patching ldflags')
        if IS_WINDOWS:
            extra_ldflags.append('/LIBPATH:{}'.format(
                _join_cuda_home('lib/x64')))
            extra_ldflags.append('cudart.lib')
            if CUDNN_HOME is not None:
                extra_ldflags.append(os.path.join(CUDNN_HOME, 'lib/x64'))
        else:
            extra_ldflags.append('-L{}'.format(_join_cuda_home('lib64')))
            extra_ldflags.append('-lcudart')
            if CUDNN_HOME is not None:
                extra_ldflags.append('-L{}'.format(os.path.join(CUDNN_HOME, 'lib64')))

    return extra_ldflags


def _get_build_directory(name, verbose):
    root_extensions_directory = os.environ.get('TORCH_EXTENSIONS_DIR')
    if root_extensions_directory is None:
        root_extensions_directory = get_default_build_root()

    if verbose:
        print('Using {} as PyTorch extensions root...'.format(
            root_extensions_directory))

    build_directory = os.path.join(root_extensions_directory, name)
    if not os.path.exists(build_directory):
        if verbose:
            print('Creating extension directory {}...'.format(build_directory))
       
        os.makedirs(build_directory)

    return build_directory

def _build_extension_module(name, build_directory, verbose):
    try:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 5):
            subprocess.run(
                ['ninja', '-v'],
                stdout=None if verbose else subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                cwd=build_directory,
                check=True)
        else:
            subprocess.check_output(
                ['ninja', '-v'],
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                cwd=build_directory)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:

        _, error, _ = sys.exc_info()
      
        message = "Error building extension '{}'".format(name)
        if hasattr(error, 'output') and error.output:
            message += ": {}".format(error.output.decode())
        raise RuntimeError(message)


def _import_module_from_library(module_name, path, is_python_module):
    
    file, path, description = imp.find_module(module_name, [path])
 
    with file:
        if is_python_module:
            return imp.load_module(module_name, file, path, description)
        else:
            return torch.ops.load_library(path)


def _write_ninja_file(path,
                      name,
                      sources,
                      extra_cflags,
                      extra_cuda_cflags,
                      extra_ldflags,
                      extra_include_paths,
                      with_cuda):
    extra_cflags = [flag.strip() for flag in extra_cflags]
    extra_cuda_cflags = [flag.strip() for flag in extra_cuda_cflags]
    extra_ldflags = [flag.strip() for flag in extra_ldflags]
    extra_include_paths = [flag.strip() for flag in extra_include_paths]


    config = ['ninja_required_version = 1.3']
    config.append('cxx = {}'.format(os.environ.get('CXX', 'c++')))
    if with_cuda:
        config.append('nvcc = {}'.format(_join_cuda_home('bin', 'nvcc')))


    sources = [os.path.abspath(file) for file in sources]
    user_includes = [os.path.abspath(file) for file in extra_include_paths]

 
    system_includes = include_paths(with_cuda)

    system_includes.append(sysconfig.get_paths()['include'])


    if IS_WINDOWS:
        user_includes += system_includes
        system_includes.clear()

    common_cflags = ['-DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME={}'.format(name)]
    common_cflags.append('-DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H')
    common_cflags += ['-I{}'.format(include) for include in user_includes]
    common_cflags += ['-isystem {}'.format(include) for include in system_includes]

    if _is_binary_build():
        common_cflags += ['-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0']

    cflags = common_cflags + ['-fPIC', '-std=c++11'] + extra_cflags
    if IS_WINDOWS:
        from distutils.spawn import _nt_quote_args
        cflags = _nt_quote_args(cflags)
    flags = ['cflags = {}'.format(' '.join(cflags))]

    if with_cuda:
        cuda_flags = common_cflags + COMMON_NVCC_FLAGS
        if IS_WINDOWS:
            cuda_flags = _nt_quote_args(cuda_flags)
        else:
            cuda_flags += ['--compiler-options', "'-fPIC'"]
            cuda_flags += extra_cuda_cflags
            if not any(flag.startswith('-std=') for flag in cuda_flags):
                cuda_flags.append('-std=c++11')

        flags.append('cuda_flags = {}'.format(' '.join(cuda_flags)))

    if IS_WINDOWS:
        ldflags = ['/DLL'] + extra_ldflags
    else:
        ldflags = ['-shared'] + extra_ldflags
    # The darwin linker needs explicit consent to ignore unresolved symbols.
    if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ldflags.append('-undefined dynamic_lookup')
    elif IS_WINDOWS:
        ldflags = _nt_quote_args(ldflags)
    flags.append('ldflags = {}'.format(' '.join(ldflags)))

    compile_rule = ['rule compile']
    if IS_WINDOWS:
        compile_rule.append(
            '  command = cl /showIncludes $cflags -c $in /Fo$out')
        compile_rule.append('  deps = msvc')
    else:
        compile_rule.append(
            '  command = $cxx -MMD -MF $out.d $cflags -c $in -o $out')
        compile_rule.append('  depfile = $out.d')
        compile_rule.append('  deps = gcc')

    if with_cuda:
        cuda_compile_rule = ['rule cuda_compile']
        cuda_compile_rule.append(
            '  command = $nvcc $cuda_flags -c $in -o $out')

    link_rule = ['rule link']
    if IS_WINDOWS:
        cl_paths = subprocess.check_output(['where',
                                            'cl']).decode().split('\r\n')
        if len(cl_paths) >= 1:
            cl_path = os.path.dirname(cl_paths[0]).replace(':', '$:')
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("MSVC is required to load C++ extensions")
        link_rule.append(
            '  command = "{}/link.exe" $in /nologo $ldflags /out:$out'.format(
                cl_path))
    else:
        link_rule.append('  command = $cxx $in $ldflags -o $out')


    object_files = []
    build = []
    for source_file in sources:
      
        file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(source_file))[0]
        if _is_cuda_file(source_file) and with_cuda:
            rule = 'cuda_compile'
           
            target = '{}.cuda.o'.format(file_name)
        else:
            rule = 'compile'
            target = '{}.o'.format(file_name)
        object_files.append(target)
        if IS_WINDOWS:
            source_file = source_file.replace(':', '$:')
        source_file = source_file.replace(" ", "$ ")
        build.append('build {}: {} {}'.format(target, rule, source_file))

    ext = 'pyd' if IS_WINDOWS else 'so'
    library_target = '{}.{}'.format(name, ext)

    link = ['build {}: link {}'.format(library_target, ' '.join(object_files))]

    default = ['default {}'.format(library_target)]

  
    blocks = [config, flags, compile_rule]
    if with_cuda:
        blocks.append(cuda_compile_rule)
    blocks += [link_rule, build, link, default]
    with open(path, 'w') as build_file:
        for block in blocks:
            lines = '\n'.join(block)
            build_file.write('{}\n\n'.format(lines))


def _join_cuda_home(*paths):

    if CUDA_HOME is None:
        raise EnvironmentError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
                               'Please set it to your CUDA install root.')
    return os.path.join(CUDA_HOME, *paths)


def _is_cuda_file(path):
    return os.path.splitext(path)[1] in ['.cu', '.cuh']
```

This is the error message :

**UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 54: invalid start byte**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It's not referring you to line 54, it's referring you to position 54 in the string in question. The stacktrace (please provide the full thing) will tell you which line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, then the solution that usually works to circumvent decoding issues like these is to do the following:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```